# Mock interface in the test class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

```
// Dao Interface
public Interface IDao {
    public void foo()
}
```

Mock interface in test class

Comment: This is the best question I've ever seen on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myDao` is a package level field so its available in the child class.
In that case you can go for the standard Mockito injection of a mock:

```
@Mock
IDao daoMock;

@InjectMocks
MySubClass subclass;

@Before
public void init(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test(){
    subclass.toCreate();

    Mockito.verify(daoMock).create();
}
```